# What's the workflow for adding CoreData to rubymotion WITHOUT using a DSL

Tags: core-data, rubymotion

I know you can include xcdatamodel resources, but what about a workflow for auto-generated NSManagedObject model files and categories? Are there any examples anywhere on the net with full fledge coredata examples on rubymotion NOT using a DSL? I would love to see an example workflow.

I'm extremely familiar with CoreData, but it seems like the rubymotion community only uses wrappers :(

Comment: "...it seems like the rubymotion community only uses wrappers :(" This is pretty true. Working with CoreData without wrappers is like doing dentistry without anesthesia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is one example of bare use of CoreData in the HipByte RubyMotion examples. It seems pretty straightforward, or as much as CoreData can be.

Check their [Locations app](https://github.com/HipByte/RubyMotionSamples/tree/master/ios/Locations), and more specifically the [LocationsStore class](https://github.com/HipByte/RubyMotionSamples/blob/master/ios/Locations/app/locations_store.rb)

Comment: Thanks, not sure how i missed this.